# encrypted ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, encryption, luks, zfs, cache

I am new to zfs.

I read, and sucessfully tested, that encrypted zfs is working.
This is a professional laptop so full encryption is required.
Current (20.04) setup is separate / and /home, both luks encrypted.
I am very comfortable using luks, and plan to move at least my /home partition to zfs, so that I can use snapshots and compression.

I would tend to like using native zfs encryption, as it "should" be a better integration.

1- reason for using compression zfs on a luks-encrypted partition would be:

a- luks has been around for a long time (= has been much more tested), so I would feel a bit more comfortable (am I wrong on this, and is zfs encryption considered production-grade ?)

b- luks can hold 8 keys; while unless I am wrong, zfs has only one password key. I feel more confortable with several  keys

- can have an usb based files set to unlock all encrypted partitions
- usually i set up with a short (eg 5-8 char) luks password; once setup up looks fine after a while, i update to a longer, more complex passphrase and remove the short one. I do that to avoid typos tied to wrong keyboard (i live in europe and sometime switch between local and american keyboard; and got bitten by this at least once; so my short temporary password is keyboard-proof). This allows me to keep both password for a while until I feel safe to remove the shorter one.

Now the questions:

1- Any reason to avoid zfs on a partition (as opposed to a full disk) ? This is not a multi-partition or disk zpool (I think I have read something about the cache not being used by defaut -if partition instead of whole disk - and requirement to activate it manually, but did not find anything sustaining that or how to solve this, and fear if true this is hiding an implementation weakness)

2- any reason to avoid zfs on a luks encrypted partition ? security / performance ? My concern here is relatively new native encryption on zfs on ubuntu -> is this production-grade ?

3- I could not easily find the documentation on how to change a ZFS dataset key :( ; any hint ?

Thanks !
[edited for minor clarification on concern]

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting You're asking for a ZFS tutorial on a Ubuntu Question & Answer site. .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Asking for a ZFS tutorial on a Ubuntu Q&A site.

Comment: I am voting the same, AFTER you or anyone else please first help with my questions (which except q3 are not a request for tutorial, but for best practices and traps for ZFS on Ubuntu, which require EXPERIENCE). I would not ask here if I would run zfs/Solaris, which I am confident is production-grade and well documented. I do ask here because what I read after googling about zfs on Ubuntu "feels weak" and not complete; and if the answers were as straightforward as you seem to imply, I believe there would already be 3 or 4 answers from people who know (and I would have found the doc by myself).

Comment: So you agree with my Close reason, but want a tutorial ("best practices for ZFS on Ubuntu") anyhow? See https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tutorial

Comment: If you have any idea on the subject matter, (in fact so far you haven't shown anything in this thread but your ignorance so far), please feel free to contribute. Otherwise dear Trollinator, stay away: you have already damaged your reputation. Thanks. Your further posts not related to zfs on Ubuntu will be ignored anyway.